# How can I add an image to a panel

Tags: java, swing

edit// my question is simpler than the other one so please just answer here. the other question looks too complicated for me to understand.

I want to add an image to a panel, but not sure how it's done. I don't want to do it from the design page because I didn't Design my panel I only coded it to show up. so does anyone know what code I need to add for an image to show up on there? and where do I save the image so that it can be included. here is the code I've done so far

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("JButton");

frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(500,200);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);

JButton button = new JButton("London"); 
panel.add(button); 

JLabel label = new JLabel("Click", JLabel.CENTER);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an image to a JPanel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel)

Comment: nope that isn't clear to me..

Comment: @RebeccaWahlestedt what is not clear?

Comment: There are various ways of doing what you ask explained in the linked page.

Comment: @RamPrakash I don't understand the code so essentially I'm asking if someone can show me the entire code so I can paste it and see if an image appears

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170094/java-using-graphics-component-within-an-action-listener/42170674#42170674)?

Comment: no not really, instead of a plain panel opening I want the panel to have an image there as the background

Comment: Then something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731882/background-image-hidding-the-other-components-like-buttons-labels-and-other-and/37734980#37734980)? (Tip: add @Frakcool (or whoever you want to reply) to notify them you're replying to them (The `@` is important))

Comment: @RebeccaWahlestedt: I hope [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230) might be able to give some insight on the problem. For further understanding, have a look at this post [Loading Image Resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230).

Comment: (1-) The first link given shows you two easy ways to do this. 1) the easiest is to use a JLabel with an image 2) next you draw the image on a panel. Frankly the code given in the first two answers of that link is a simple as it gets. There is no simpler way.

Comment: @Frakcool yes that's how I want it to appear, to test it out I copied your code and tested it, everything works except the image because I don't have that image. so I copied an image url from google and pasted it in and it didn't appear? what can I do

Comment: @RebeccaWahlestedt please edit your question to include the code you have modified

Comment: @RebeccaWahlestedt Try changing: `new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Frakcool/workspace/StackOverflowProjects/src/test/Air.jpg")` for `newImageIcon(new URL("yourImageUrl"));` and import `import java.net.URL;` in your program, that should do the trick, if that helps let me know

Comment: it finally works how I want it! thanks everyone especially @nIcEcOw

Comment: @RebeccaWahlestedt: Glad the link did helped you in some way :-) For the rest YOU're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
       try {                
          image = ImageIO.read(new File("image name and path"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters            
    }

}
```

Comment: It's generally helpful to provide some explanation to go with your code.

Comment: this code looks too complicated to me. I've just started to understand basic coding but this is way too much. could you modify the code so it fits with mine?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is,

1. Read image file.
2. Draw image to background with help of `Graphics` object.

just replace  `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` with below code.

```
         JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
             @Override
             protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                 Image image = null;
                 try {
                     image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png"));
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 super.paintComponent(g);
                 g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
             }
         };
```

Comment: it says cannot find symbol under ImageIO and IOException?

Comment: well, you need to add import statement for these 2 classes

Answer (score 0):

Alright, there are 2 ways to add your image:

1. Using custom painting by overriding [`JPanel#paintComponent(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method.
2. Using a `JLabel` to display the image and applying to it various [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to get the desired GUI.

---

I'm going to expand on how to use the 1st way with some comments in the code, the original idea was given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299555/2180785) so, be sure to give credits to the author.

You need to either:

- Create a custom `JPanel` object
- Create a class that extends `JPanel`

In any case you need to override the `paintComponent(...)` method.

Later, in that `paintComponent()` method you need to draw the image using [`Graphics#drawImage(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) method. This will make the `JPanel` to draw the image as the background.

After that you should override your `JPanel`'s [`getPreferredSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getPreferredSize()) method, so you can call [`JFrame#pack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()), which will resize your `JFrame`'s size to its preferred size (which is the minimum size where all your components are visible).

After doing that, you can easily add components as you've always done:

```
panel.add(...);
```

And the second way is to make a `JLabel` to act as a Container, where you can add more Components to it (just like you do in a `JPanel`) (As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731882/background-image-hidding-the-other-components-like-buttons-labels-and-other-and/37734980#37734980))

The way to do this is:

- Create a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`
- Set its layout manager
- Add components to it

---

Depending on which one you choose you have some differences:

- Using the custom painting option, you need to take care of the preferred size of your container but you have more control over your component. However the image will fill all the space available on the window.
- Using the `JLabel` option you can simply call `pack()` on your `JFrame` and it will resize to the image size, but if your image is too big your `JFrame` will be the same size too. If you resize your window to be shorter the image will be cropped and show "white" space if you make your window bigger.

This is how the image looks like with the 2 options, on the left the custom painting, on the right the label approach. At first they both look the same...

[image]

But... If we resize the window, this is what we get:

[image]
[image]

I like the custom painting approach more, but it depends on your needs and likes.

The code that produces the above output is:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JPanelWithBackgroundImageExample {

    private JFrame frame; //Our window
    private JPanel panel; //The panel where we're going to draw the background image
    private Image image;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JPanelWithBackgroundImageExample().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg")); //We read the image from the Internet
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        panel = new JPanel() { //We need to open the curly braces so we can change the default behavior of the JPanel
            /* 
             * This method is the one that paints the background, by default it paints it with gray color,
             * so, we need to tell it to draw an image instead. (This method belongs to JPanel already, so we need to add
             * "@Override" before it, so the compiler knows we're overriding it
             */
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g); //Never forget this line or you could break the paint chain

                /* 
                 * This method belongs to the Graphics class and draws an image, this is what we want the JPanel to draw as our background
                 * The parameters are: the image to be drawn, the starting position (x, y) coords, the width and height and the observer
                 */
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
            }

            /* 
             * This method is part of the JPanel, we're overriding it's preferred size and return the size we want
             */
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 200);
            }
        };

        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)); //We create a JLabel that will act as a container for our components

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE)); //We create a border just for visibility of both ways
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE)); //We create a border just for visibility of both ways

        label.setLayout(new BoxLayout(label, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); //We set the layout manager for the label

        label.add(new JLabel("I'm a label inside a label")); //We add a new label to our label (that is acting as a container)
        label.add(new JButton("I'm a button inside a label")); //We add a button to our label (that is acting as a container)

        //You can add your components to the panel, as you always do it
        panel.add(new JButton("HEY! I'm a button!")); //We add a button to our jpanel
        panel.add(new JLabel("Click the button next to me! :D")); //We add a label to our jpanel

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST); //We add the pane which has a size of 300 x 200 to the left part of our JFrame
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.EAST); //We add the label (which acts as a container / jpanel) to the right part of our JFrame
        frame.pack(); //We pack the frame, so it takes its preferred size (and as we only added a single component to it (the JPanel)
                        //As the panel has a size of 300 x 200, the frame will also have this size
        frame.setVisible(true); //We set the visibility of the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Now, as a general tip, place your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) by changing your `main()` method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your constructor here
        }
    });
}
```

And now, to answer your question in the comments:

> everything works except the image because I don't have that image. so I copied an image url from google and pasted it in and it didn't appear? what can I do

Well, I think you took the code from the linked answer and changed this line:

```
frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Frakcool/workspace/StackOverflowProjects/src/test/Air.jpg")));
```

To something like this:

```
frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg")));
```

Well in that case, it's obvious that the code won't work that way, Swing doesn't know how to interpret a `http` in a String, but [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class does, and thus, you should change the above line like:

```
frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg"))));
```

And import:

```
import java.net.URL;
```

In your class.

I hope this helps you in understanding how the code works, if not, well, I think you need to put more effort in understanding it.